# How to push ASC order wise while using array with particular key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here i am having one array and i am using foreach & and writing if condition as well every thing working fine,my question is, else condition `array_push($priorityList4, $temp)` , i am doing this

`activationDate` ASC order wise i have to push the data into `$priorityList4`

> My Code

```
<?php
$priorityList4 = $priorityList0 = [];
$pedagogyTopics = Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "pedagogyID" => "1",
                    "status" => "complete",
                    "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 16:21:06"
                ),

            "1" => Array
                (
                    "pedagogyID" => "2",
                    "status" => "in-progress",
                    "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 15:19:22"
                ),
            "2" => Array
                (
                    "pedagogyID" => "3",
                    "status" => "in-progress",
                    "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 14:19:22"
                )

        );
foreach ($pedagogyTopics as $topic) {
    $temp = [
                "contentID" => $topic['pedagogyID'],
                "status" => isset($topic['status']) ? $topic['status'] : null,
                "activationDate" => $topic['activationDate'],
            ];

            if($topic['status'] != 'complete'){
                 array_push($priorityList0, $temp);
            }else{
                 array_push($priorityList4, $temp); // Here activationDate ASC order wise i have to push
            }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_merge($priorityList0 , $priorityList4));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

> Getting Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 2
            [status] => in-progress
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 15:19:22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 3
            [status] => in-progress
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 14:19:22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 1
            [status] => complete
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 16:21:06
        )

)
```

> Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 3
            [status] => in-progress
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 14:19:22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 2
            [status] => in-progress
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 15:19:22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 1
            [status] => complete
            [activationDate] => 2018-11-28 16:21:06
        )

)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_asort.asp

Comment: I'd suggest learning how to leverage http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php as you can create a function to help with your special sorting needs

Comment: is contentId is unique in your array ?

Comment: @ kmg kumar . Yes, Kindly update your answer

Comment: Please anyone update your answer, i tried lot, but not able to do